# Using the NuxtJS Strapi Module in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I am using `@nuxt/strapi` as a wrapper around `Strapi` for `NuxtJS`.
For Vuex inside Nuxt I am using the namespaced modules mode, so my structure looks as an example like this:

```
store
├── user.js
├── posts.js
└── index.js
```

In a `Vue` project I would import Vue, Vuex, maybe Axios and then create a store instance `const store = new Vuex.Store(storeOptions)` and dispatch my initial actions or make some API calls from inside `store/index.js`.

Example for index.js in a vue project:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Vue from 'vue';
import user from './modules/user'
import posts from './modules/posts'
Vue.use(Vuex);
const storeOptions = { ... }
const store = new Vuex.Store(storeOptions)

if (user) {
  ...
  store.dispatch('startPageLoading', 'store');
  store.commit('SET_USER', user);
  await store.dispatch("getSomeData");
  ...
}
```

But in a Nuxt project the store and the strapi instances already were created in `root_project/.nuxt/...`. So what is the best way to use $strapi and $store inside `store/index.js`? Neither `$strapi` or `$store` are available in `store/index.js`

Comment: what do you mean with *use .. $store inside store/index.js* ? `store/index.js` is already an store

Comment: If I work with store modules, I still would have to do something like `store.dispatch("something")` inside `store/index.js`

Comment: well... not really i guess. could you give me more context for clarify

Comment: I have updated the question with some example code. My question is do I have to create manually a store and strapi instance or can I somehow use the things Nuxt has already created for me in `.nuxt/...`

Comment: please ignore the `.nuxt` folder, we shouldnt change something in it there are some internal stuff in it.

Answer (score 0):

there is this `nuxtServerInit` action that gets executed on the server side after you open / refresh page.

You can only do it in `index.js` file

This is how your index.js could look like:

```
//index.js
export const state = () => ({
   someState: false
})


export const mutations = {
  SOME_MUTATION(state, payload) {
    ...
  }
}

export const actions = {
  SOME_ACTION({ state, commit }, payload) {
     ...
  },
  nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { $strapi }){
     //do here something on the server side...
  }
}
```

The documentation says if you added the strapi module to your project, you should be able to access it from the context. The context is the second argument from `nuxtServerInit`

Thats it. This is how a store could look like, nothing fancy.

You could dispatch / commit something from any component with

```
this.$store.commit("SOME_MUTATION")
```

They say its global available with `this.$strapi`

> This module globally injects $strapi instance, meaning that you can access it anywhere using this.$strapi. For plugins, asyncData, fetch, nuxtServerInit and Middleware, you can access it from context.$strapi.